# Java ternary operator logic explanation

Tags: java, ternary-operator

Can someone please explain what this line of java code is doing?

```
public String getTitleNavContainer(boolean isThisLandingPage) {
    return isThisLandingPage ? StringUtils.EMPTY : "title-nav-container";
}
```

I can see what it is doing but I am wondering how I would modify this so that if it is landing page it does one thing otherwise do something else.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `...does one thing otherwise do something else` - what thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above line is called `ternary operator`

`Ternary Operator` takes three parameter and its sudo code is

```
condition ? statement1 : statement2
```

**Condition:** This part should have valid conditional statement and that should return only boolean value

**Statement1:** If condition is `true` then `statement1` will execute

**Statement2:** If condition is `false` then `statement2` will execute

Now look at your code block

```
public String getTitleNavContainer(boolean isThisLandingPage) {
   return isThisLandingPage ? StringUtils.EMPTY : "title-nav-container";
}
```

if `isThisLandingPage` is `true` then `StringUtils.EMPTY` will execute else `title-nav-container` execute

For quick understanding, convert the code as `if-else` statement

```
if (isThisLandingPage)
{
   return StringUtils.EMPTY;
}
else
{
   return title-nav-container;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
return isThisLandingPage ? StringUtils.EMPTY : "title-nav-container";
```

is the same as:

```
public String getTitleNavContainer(boolean isThisLandingPage) {
    if ( isThisLandingPage ){
      return StringUtils.EMPTY;
    }
    else{
      return "title-nav-container";
    }
}
```

It's just a shorter way to write it, making the code easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the ternary operator (or the conditional operator) is an alternative to the Java if/then/else syntax, but it goes beyond that, and can even be used on the right hand side of Java statements.

Basically it evaluates the predicate

```
;(boolean expression)   (if it is true)     (if it is false)

isThisLandingPage    ? StringUtils.EMPTY : "title-nav-container";
```

And this expression returns that value depending on the boolean expression, this value is the one that the function returns the Empty String "" from this [class doc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) or the String "title-nav-container".

I hope this help you